# How to implement ascending or descending in the table with ant vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, antd

When you click `↑` on the second line, `B` moves to the first line and `A` moves to the second line. When you click `↓` on the first line, `B` moves to the second line, A moves to the first line, and each line clicks the ascending descending event. How to solve the above problem?

**click `↑`**

[image]

**click `↓`**

[image]

My code：

```
<template>
  <a-table :columns="columns" :dataSource="data" @change="onChange">
    <template slot="sort" slot-scope="text, record">
      <span @click="orderFn(record)">↑</span>
      <span @click="orderFn(record)">↓</span>
    </template>
  </a-table>
</template>
<script>
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age"
  },
  {
    title: "sort",
    dataIndex: "sort",
    scopedSlots: { customRender: "sort" },
    align: "center"
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "A",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "B",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "C",
    age: 30
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    name: "D",
    age: 40
  }
];

function onChange(pagination, filters, sorter) {
  console.log("params", pagination, filters, sorter);
}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data,
      columns
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onChange,
    orderFn(record){
      console.log(record)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

*The demo is as follows：*
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-antd-template-4hoyh)

Comment: I had a play around and it seems to be working? Can you explain the problem again?

Comment: I have solved it.

Comment: Can you post the solution @wentian